# PHP is not supported in code editor websites

Tags: php, html

This is an example of: When php cant work in some websites.

I was trying to make a `Search_Query` but it doesn’t work. Even `inspect element` doesn’t work. They made the code like:

```
<!--<?php echo "hello" ?>-->
```

i do not know why but it happens.

here's my files:

[index.html](https://yantoxsoft.w3spaces.com/index.html):

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Home - Yantoxsoft</title>

        <!-- Load external CSS styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <!-- Load website icon -->
        <link rel='shortcut icon' href='icon.jpeg'>

    </head>

    <body>

        <form action='search.html'>
        
        <label for='search_query'>
        Search:<input name='search_query'><input type="submit">
        </label>

        </form>
        
        <!-- Load external JavaScript -->
        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

[search.html](https://yantoxsoft.w3spaces.com/search.html):

```html
<form action='search.html' method='POST'>
        
    <label for='search_query'>
        <input name='search_query'>
    </label>

</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // collect value of input field
  $search = $_POST['search_query'];
  if (empty($search)) {
    echo "No Results for: " + $search;
  } else {
    echo "results for:" + $search;
  }
}
?>
```

and do not answer with `.php` files because they are not supported :/

Because they only make `.css`, `.js`, and `.html` files and image or gif files. Why not `python`, `lua`, `mp4`, or `php`? Who knows.

Comment: If the site doesn't support php scripting - not sure what you expect it to do with the php code?

Comment: I COULD JUST CREATE A PHP FILE WITH NOTEPAD++, THAT WILL WORK TOO.

Comment: BUT I DO NOT DOWNLOAD NOTEPAD++ though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please save PHP file with .php extension and use html tag inside as: `echo "<h1>Hello Dev!</h1>";`

i.e after saving your code in .php format

```
<?php

echo "<form action='search.html' method='POST'>
        
    <label for='search_query'>
        <input name='search_query'>
    </label>

</form>";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // collect value of input field
  $search = $_POST['search_query'];
  if (empty($search)) {
    echo "No Results for: " + $search;
  } else {
    echo "results for:" + $search;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A PHP Script will never work in a file with `.html` extension. You already said your hosting provider doesn't allow `.php`. You don't have any other problem. You either forget about your search functionality or change your host!

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML files won't be processed by PHP engine but You've saved everything in an html file so it's clear why it doesn't work.

Change the extension from `.html` to `.php` and if your hosting service provider doesn't support PHP, you have to find another one.